# I am implementing Android application but there is one issue

Tags: android

When I'm going to invite my friends through my developing app to WhatsApp, if I click to invite my friend and then WhatsApp contact list comes up and I do not want to invite any friend. Why my invitation count is going to decrease by one?

Answer (score 0):

On a high level: Because you have set your counter to work whenever you go to the page, not to whenever you add a contact.